# How to deserialzie XML object based on attribute value of the child object c#?

Tags: c#, xml

How to deserialzie XML object based on attribute value of the child object?

For example I got this

```
<List>
  <Person>
    <M id= Name v="Chris">
    <M id= Year v="12">
    <M id= Haircolor v="blond">
    <M id= HairLength v="10">
  </Person >
  <Person>
    <M id= Name v="Sara">
    <M id= Year v="9">
    <M id= Haircolor v="Brown">
    <M id= HairLength v="20">
  </Person >
  <Person>
    <M id= Name v="Noelle">
    <M id= Year v="20">
    <M id= Haircolor v="Gray">
    <M id= HairLength v="30">
  </Person >      <Person>
</List>
```

How can I deserialize this? I'm using XElement to choose only the Descendants("Person"), then I'm getting all the XML part for Person.
My problem is that since all elements has the same ElementName = M, I don't know how to separate each Element M to be a class property value. I tried to do XMLElement("M"), but it would interpret everything as the same. A solution that worked for me is to use "order" in the XmlElement, but this approach is not bullettproof as you sometime can get null values, so it would place the values in wrong class property.

In this case I got a model that looks like this:

```
public class Person 
{    
  public string Name {get; set;}
  public string Year {get; set;}      
  public string Haircolor {get; set;}      
  public string HairLength {get; set;}
}
```

I want the M element with Id name to correspond to Name in the class, and ID year in M element to correspond Year etc...

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Are you able to deserialize the XML at all? If you are then that's most of the battle. Don't try to deserialize it directly into your `Person` class. Instead, deserialize it into anything and then map that to the final class you want. In other words, convert the "weird" deserialized class you don't want into the better class that you do want.

Comment: I manage to deserialize it fine, but my problem is forexample since I use the order value, whenever the Name element doesn't have value, the year value automatically falls into Name property...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given an `XmlDocument` loaded with the XML, this will use XPath queries to parse the file:

```
IEnumerable<Person> ReadPeople(XmlDocument document)
{
    var result = new List<Person>();
    var root = document.DocumentElement;
    var personNodes = root.SelectNodes("Person");
    foreach (XmlElement personNode in personNodes)
    {
        var person = new Person
        {
            Name = personNode.SelectSingleNode("M[@id='Name']")?.Attributes["v"]?.Value,
            Haircolor = personNode.SelectSingleNode("M[@id='Haircolor']")?.Attributes["v"]?.Value,
            HairLength = personNode.SelectSingleNode("M[@id='HairLength']")?.Attributes["v"]?.Value,
            Year = personNode.SelectSingleNode("M[@id='Year']")?.Attributes["v"]?.Value
        };

        result.Add(person);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Example:

```
var document = new XmlDocument();
document.Load(File.OpenRead("XmlFile1.xml"));
var people = ReadPeople(document);
```

It does the following:

- Select all of the Person nodes within the root element
- For each Person node, select the M element with each expected id attribute and assign the value of the v attribute to the corresponding property of the `Person` object.

For my testing I had to clean up some aspects of the XML, so the document I'm loading looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<List>
  <Person>
    <M id= "Name" v="Chris"/>
    <M id= "Year" v="12"/>
    <M id= "Haircolor" v="blond"/>
    <M id= "HairLength" v="10"/>
  </Person >
  <Person>
    <M id= "Name" v="Sara"/>
    <M id= "Year" v="9"/>
    <M id= "Haircolor" v="Brown"/>
    <!--<M id= "HairLength" v="20"/>-->
  </Person >

</List>
```

The original was malformed - missing closing tags and quotes around attribute values.

This included removing one element to ensure that nulls were handled correctly.

---

Or, if you prefer something slightly less repetitive you can use a local function to retrieve a given id and use a LINQ query.

```
IEnumerable<Person> ReadPeople(XmlDocument document)
{
    string GetAttribute(XmlElement personNode, string id) =>
        personNode.SelectSingleNode($"M[@id='{id}']")?.Attributes["v"]?.Value;

    return document.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("Person").Cast<XmlElement>()
        .Select(node =>
            new Person
            {
                Name = GetAttribute(node, "Name"),
                Haircolor = GetAttribute(node, "Haircolor"),
                HairLength = GetAttribute(node, "HairLength"),
                Year = GetAttribute(node, "Year")
            });
}
```